# How to format an integer data variable value to display last two digits in java using Decimal Format

Tags: decimalformat

How to format an integer data variable value to display last two digits in java using Decimal Format..
For instance suppose i have this variable int year=1999 I want to extract last two digits ie-99 and display it.But this should be done using Decimal Format...Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: year % 100 will give you the last two digits, why do you need DecimalFormat?

Comment: I thought the same but I was required to try using DecimalFormat. I dont know if thats possible so thought of asking. Anywas thanks for the help though.(y)